# pandas_ta Technical Indicators

Tags: python, pandas, finance, pandas-ta

I am very new to this, and looking for some help.    I have a .csv file which I have pulled into a dataframe.   It contains 200 days of tickers, open, high, low & close prices.

I am trying to use pandas_ta (sma) to calculate the 10, 50 & 100 day SMA.   I tried did 3 commands:

```
df.ta.sma(length=10, append=True)
df.ta.sma(length=50, append=True)
df.ta.sma(length=100, append=True)
```

But I do not think this is the way.  I see hundreds of variations on this, and not sure what to do.

If I try this:

```
df.ta.sma(df["Close"].values),
```

it gives me some Keyword error on "Close".  (KeyError: 'Close')

Was hoping someone can give me an example on the syntax and such.   I also have to calculate RSI & MACD for this task.

Many thanks!

Comment: Added a new tag `pandas-ta`, since [`this`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-ta/) package has been used here.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to use:

```
import pandas_ta  as ta
```

And I've used it like your examples with ema, with the exception my OHLC is all lower case. Check your actual syntax: it is close or Close?

```
df.ta.ema(df['close'], length=14, offset=None, append=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the dataframe to pandas_ta it will find the close column so you do not need to specify it.
"Close". (KeyError: 'Close') is caused by the column label. You will have to rename the column to 'close' from 'Close'.

```
import pandas_ta as ta
df[SMA 10] = df.ta.sma(10)
df[SMA 50] = df.ta.sma(50)
df[SMA 100] = df.ta.sma(100)
```

Alternatively, you could do it this way as well.

```
sma10 = df.ta.sma(10)
sma50 = df.ta.sma(50)
sma100 = df.ta.sma(100)
df = pd.concat([df, sma10, sma50, sma100], axis=1)
```